# Extracting a specific element from a webpage in Python using requests-html

Tags: python, css, web-scraping, python-requests-html

Say I'm looking at this webpage

https://openpaymentsdata.cms.gov/search/physicians/by-name-and-location?firstname=robert&lastname=b&city=Palo_Alto

I want to extract the link to that physician's profile, but when I try web scraping, I can't find the element, even when using the CSS selector.

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

firstname = 'robert'
lastname = 'b'
city = 'Palo_Alto'

url = 'https://openpaymentsdata.cms.gov/search/physicians/by-name-and-location?firstname='\
        + firstname + '&lastname=' + lastname + '&city=' + city

session = HTMLSession()

r = session.get(url)

sel = 'body > div.siteOuterWrapper > div.siteInnerWrapper > div.siteContentWrapper'
print(r.html.find(sel, first=True).text)
```

This all works until I get to the content wrapper, where I can no longer see any elements. Why is this? Is there a reason I can't see this element? I thought it was because of Javascript at first, but this library claims to have full javascript support https://requests-html.kennethreitz.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTTP request below should return the data you are looking for. (In the browser do F12 > Network > XHR)

```
HTTP GET https://openpaymentsdata.cms.gov/resource/khdp-6xuy.json?%24select=%3Aid%2Cphysician_profile_id%2Cphysician_profile_last_name%2Cphysician_profile_middle_name%2Cphysician_profile_first_name%2Cphysician_profile_suffix%2Cphysician_profile_primary_specialty%2Cphysician_profile_address_line_1%2Cphysician_profile_address_line_2%2Cphysician_profile_city%2Cphysician_profile_state%2Cphysician_profile_province_name%2Cphysician_profile_country_name%2Cphysician_profile_zipcode%2Cphysician_profile_alternate_first_name1%2Cphysician_profile_alternate_last_name1%2Cphysician_profile_alternate_first_name2%2Cphysician_profile_alternate_last_name2%2Cphysician_profile_alternate_first_name3%2Cphysician_profile_alternate_last_name3%2Cphysician_profile_alternate_first_name4%2Cphysician_profile_alternate_last_name4%2Cphysician_profile_alternate_first_name5%2Cphysician_profile_alternate_last_name5%2Clocation&%24where=STARTS_WITH(UPPER(physician_profile_first_name)%2C%20%27ROBERT%27)%20AND%20STARTS_WITH(UPPER(physician_profile_last_name)%2C%20%27B%27)%20AND%20STARTS_WITH(UPPER(physician_profile_city)%2C%20%27PALO_ALTO%27)&%24order=physician_profile_last_name%20ASC%2Cphysician_profile_first_name%20ASC&%24limit=300
```

Using requests

```
print(requests.get('https://openpaymentsdata.cms.gov/resource/khdp-6xuy.json?%24select=%3Aid%2Cphysician_profile_id%2Cphysician_profile_last_name%2Cphysician_profile_middle_name%2Cphysician_profile_first_name%2Cphysician_profile_suffix%2Cphysician_profile_primary_specialty%2Cphysician_profile_address_line_1%2Cphysician_profile_address_line_2%2Cphysician_profile_city%2Cphysician_profile_state%2Cphysician_profile_province_name%2Cphysician_profile_country_name%2Cphysician_profile_zipcode%2Cphysician_profile_alternate_first_name1%2Cphysician_profile_alternate_last_name1%2Cphysician_profile_alternate_first_name2%2Cphysician_profile_alternate_last_name2%2Cphysician_profile_alternate_first_name3%2Cphysician_profile_alternate_last_name3%2Cphysician_profile_alternate_first_name4%2Cphysician_profile_alternate_last_name4%2Cphysician_profile_alternate_first_name5%2Cphysician_profile_alternate_last_name5%2Clocation&%24where=STARTS_WITH(UPPER(physician_profile_first_name)%2C%20%27ROBERT%27)%20AND%20STARTS_WITH(UPPER(physician_profile_last_name)%2C%20%27B%27)%20AND%20STARTS_WITH(UPPER(physician_profile_city)%2C%20%27PALO_ALTO%27)&%24order=physician_profile_last_name%20ASC%2Cphysician_profile_first_name%20ASC&%24limit=300').json())
```

output

```
[{':id': 'row-9mfk-w6hd-ejup', 'physician_profile_id': '966387', 'physician_profile_last_name': 'BOCIAN', 'physician_profile_middle_name': 'C', 'physician_profile_first_name': 'ROBERT', 'physician_profile_primary_specialty': 'Allopathic & Osteopathic Physicians|Allergy & Immunology|Allergy', 'physician_profile_address_line_1': '795 EL CAMINO REAL', 'physician_profile_city': 'PALO ALTO', 'physician_profile_state': 'CA', 'physician_profile_country_name': 'UNITED STATES', 'physician_profile_zipcode': '94301-2302', 'physician_profile_alternate_first_name1': 'ROBERT', 'physician_profile_alternate_last_name1': 'BOCIAN'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

The site you mentioned gets it's data from an API - [this](https://openpaymentsdata.cms.gov/resource/khdp-6xuy.json?%24select=%3Aid%2Cphysician_profile_id%2Cphysician_profile_last_name%2Cphysician_profile_middle_name%2Cphysician_profile_first_name%2Cphysician_profile_suffix%2Cphysician_profile_primary_specialty%2Cphysician_profile_address_line_1%2Cphysician_profile_address_line_2%2Cphysician_profile_city%2Cphysician_profile_state%2Cphysician_profile_province_name%2Cphysician_profile_country_name%2Cphysician_profile_zipcode%2Cphysician_profile_alternate_first_name1%2Cphysician_profile_alternate_last_name1%2Cphysician_profile_alternate_first_name2%2Cphysician_profile_alternate_last_name2%2Cphysician_profile_alternate_first_name3%2Cphysician_profile_alternate_last_name3%2Cphysician_profile_alternate_first_name4%2Cphysician_profile_alternate_last_name4%2Cphysician_profile_alternate_first_name5%2Cphysician_profile_alternate_last_name5%2Clocation&%24where=STARTS_WITH(UPPER(physician_profile_first_name)%2C%20%27ROBERT%27)%20AND%20STARTS_WITH(UPPER(physician_profile_last_name)%2C%20%27B%27)%20AND%20STARTS_WITH(UPPER(physician_profile_city)%2C%20%27PALO_ALTO%27)&%24order=physician_profile_last_name%20ASC%2Cphysician_profile_first_name%20ASC&%24limit=300).

You can directly make `GET` requests to that API using `requests` and fetch your data.

You can find the API endpoint using Chrome Devtools.